# Why does react number format input field lose focus in nextjs on production build

Tags: reactjs, next.js, production-environment, react-number-format

Why some of the input fields in our [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) project rendered using [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) lose focus while typing? No errors are being thrown and the build logs does not indicate that something has been broken.

This happens **only** on production build.

[nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) version is 12.0.7

[react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) version is 4.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case someone come across the same issue:

After following [nextjs upgrade guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading) from v11 to v12 we [replaced Terser with SWC for minifying](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#swc-replacing-terser-for-minification) and after changing it back to Terser the issue was resolved.

in *next.config.js* file:

```
module.exports = withTM({
swcMinify: false,
...
})
```

This was also mentioned [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30237#discussioncomment-1876886) as part of the [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) feedback thread about SWC.